# Testing parity of number of items

Tags: c++, beginner, classes

This is my first C++ program with classes, and I don't want to develop bad skills. It's very simple and consists of 3 files.  This is an exercise from a book, hence the name of the driver file.

Please tell me whether it's proper or not!

**parity.cpp:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parity.h"

void Parity::put(int number)
{
    numbers.push_back(number);
}

bool Parity::test(void)
{
    if (numbers.size() % 2 == 0)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

**parity.h:**

```
#ifndef PARITY_H_
#define PATITY_H_

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Parity
{
    private:
        std::vector<int> numbers;
    public:
        void put(int number);
        bool test(void);
};

#endif
```

**13_1.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parity.h"

int main()
{
    int number;
    bool odd_number;
    Parity parity_test;

    while(true)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> number;
        if (number == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            parity_test.put(number);
            odd_number = parity_test.test();
            std::cout << odd_number;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[Some general guidelines regarding `#include`s](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/):

- only `#include` in the header when necessary (this reduces potentially unwanted dependencies)
- whenever possible, forward declare in the header instead of using `#include`
- whenever possible, `#include` in the implementation only (this does not affect dependency)
- never `#include` a source file (having to do so indicates a hierarchy issue)
- be sure to never allow files to `#include` each other (sort of in a "circular" manner)

---

- You have a typo in your header guard:

  ```
  #ifndef PARITY_H_
  #define PATITY_H_ // should be PARITY_H_
  ```
- The class isn't doing anything with `<iostream>` and `<string>`, so just remove them.
- `test()` doesn't need the `void` parameter; that's only for C.
- This:

  ```
  if (numbers.size() % 2 == 0)
      return true;
  else return false;
  ```

  can be shortened to this:

  ```
  return (numbers.size() % 2 == 0); // the statement's Boolean value is returned
  ```
- You can use [`std::boolalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/) to display a `bool` as "true" for `1` or "false" for `0`:

  ```
  std::cout << std::boolalpha << odd_number;
  ```
- The `while` and `if-else` don't seem too intuitive.  The loop just runs until you `break` from it, and it's not directly tied to `number`.  One alternative is to do an initial input before the loop:

  ```
  // initial input before loop-- number may be 0
  std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
  int number; // move the declaration here
  std::cin >> number;

  // if not 0, proceed until it's 0
  while (number != 0)
  {
      parity_test.put(number);
      bool odd_number = parity_test.test(); // initialize here instead
      std::cout << "odd number? " << std::boolalpha << odd_number;

      // input again
      std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
      std::cin >> number;
  }
  ```

Comment: thank you :) 
so the usage of classes is okay?

Comment: For this objective?  I suppose.  Even if this could be more concise and/or more logical as a procedural program, it's good to get into classes as soon as possible.  I think this is an okay start, and you haven't yet made any serious class-related mistakes.  You're free to search for other good examples of classes and do something else like it.

Comment: Keep up the learning (as I will continue to do as well)!  These are good questions.

Comment: Excellent review.  To avoid repeating the prompt code, I would structure it like this: 

    `while (cout << "Enter an integer: ",
           cin >> number,
           number != 0) {
        parity_test.put(number);
     }`

(with a newline after each comma, which I can't render in this comment).

Comment: @200_success: Yeah, I was thinking about the repeated prompt code.  @druciferre's `do-while` loop is a great alternative, but I've also heard some say that such a loop may be less-readable at times (not too sure why, though).  Either way, there's different ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

All of Jamal's points are correct, so I won't repeat those.  However, I think two essential things were missed.

First of all, you don't need to store a vector of numbers here, so don't.  I'm not sure why you'd want to in the first place; perhaps it eases debugging, or something to that effect.  However, if that's the goal, some kind of logging sounds significantly more sensible.

Secondly, `test` doesn't modify the object it is called on, and should thus be `const`.

Put together:

```
// parity.h

class Parity
{
    private:
        bool parity = true;

    public:
        void put(int number);
        bool test() const;
};
```

Note that this also saves you some includes.

```
// parity.cpp

void Parity::put(int number) {
    // use number for whatever debugging purposes you had.
    parity = !parity;
}

bool Parity::test() const {
    return parity;
}
```

In your `main` function, you should reduce the scopes of some things, but nothing significant.

Comment: Ah, I've forgotten about the `const`.  I suppose `int number` could also be `const` in `put()`, but that's not as important as the one you've mentioned.

Comment: If you're not storing ints anymore, then naming the function `put` seems a bit misleading.  But eh.

Comment: @cHao I'm guessing the "put" has some kind of semantic in the context this is written in.  This is an implementation change, so I'd say either the name was wrong to begin with, or it remains correct.

Answer (score 3):

Did you consider making your `Parity` class a template class that inherits from `std::vector`? This would provide your parity class with all of the features of `std::vector`, prevent you from having to redefine `push_back(...)`, and allow you to use your `Parity` class with types other than `int`.

#### Parity.h

```
#ifndef PARITY_H_
#define PARITY_H_

#include <vector>

template<typename _T> class Parity: public std::vector<_T>
{
    public:
        bool test()
        {
            return this->size() % 2 == 0;
        }
};

#endif
```

Rather than breaking out of your loop, or using a `while(...)` loop and having to write the code for the prompt twice, it would be better to with a `do... while(...)` loop. Also, something a wise person once told me was to get in the habit of putting literal numbers on the left hand side of logical comparisons. This prevents you from doing this `while( number = 0 )` when you meant to do this `while( number != 0 )` or `while( number == 0 )`. The compiler will throw an error if you do `while( 0 = number )`.

#### 13_1.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "parity.h"

int main()
{
    int number;
    Parity<int> parity_test;

    do
    {
        std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";
        std::cin >> number;
        parity_test.push_back(number);
        std::cout << std::boolalpha << parity_test.test() << " ";;
    }
    while( 0 != number);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Jamal The do-while loop is not *quite* identical in behaviour to the original, if the first input is `0`.

Comment: @200_success: Ah, right.  Here, if the first input is zero, the functions will still be called.  For mine, the entire loop (with the function calls) will be skipped.  Compared to the OP's, mine looks more similar (but that doesn't mean it's automatically better).

Comment: @Jamal It's important not to introduce subtle bugs during code review.  =)  If you change the behaviour, it should be intentional.

Comment: [Inheriting from standard containers is generally not recommended](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2034916/559931); is there a particular reason this is an exception?  (Also, `test` should still be `const` and `_T` is a reserved name.)

Answer (score 0):

Taking the minimalist approach, a class is not necessary since the function itself can contain enough state using a static function variable:

```
bool put(int)
{
    static bool hasParity = false;
    return hasParity = !hasParity;
}
```

Comment: This breaks as soon as you want to store multiple parities.  You also can't read the parity without flipping it.